# Как сделать, чтоб при открытие юзером ссылки ведущую на мой сайт — ему открывалось целевая страница моего сайта и скрытая (парнерская) страница?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, редирект, скрипт

Как сделать, чтоб при открытие юзером ссылки ведущую на **мой сайт** - ему открывалось целевая страница **моего сайта**, а так же и в скрытом или свернутом виде **еще одна страница** (страница партнерки) и сразу же эта страница закрывалась ?

Это мне нужно, для того чтоб в парнерке засчитывался переход юзером, а также у этого юзера будут сохраняться куки партнерки (куки живут 30 дней )

Видел подобные "манипуляции с окнами" на разных рекламных сайтах и порно-сайтах.
Поисковики мой сайт быстро забанят? Если открывать окно 1х1 и не закрывать его, то что на счёт бана?

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 0):

Поисковики такое забанят. А если ты правда хочешь такое реализовать, то это довольно просто. Пишешь скрипт:

```
window.open('твой url');
```

URL ДОЛЖЕН ВЕСТИ НА ДРУГУЮ СТРАНИЦУ ТВОЕГО САЙТА, где ты уже спарсишь страницу твоего партнера (или добавляешь через фрагмент), а также дополняешь скриптом:

```
window.onload = function() {
   window.close();
};
```

Comment: поисковики забанят мой сайт!? ну так если зарегать свежий домен и такой сайт сделать просто для для редиректа. Пользователь жмакает по ссылке, его перебрасывает на мой нормальный сайт, а также открывается +это скрытое окно?
Ну и пусть поисковки банят свежий домен, так как он не нуждается в SEO трафике. Мой основной сайт не забанят,  ведь редирект ведет также на мой основной сайт?

Comment: Можно попробовать, но не уверен, сработает или нет, потому что раньше не пытался такое сделать. Если ты решил так сделать, то url должен вести на страницу-обработчик, неважно на каком домене. А потом просто строишь страницу в конце который добавляешь код, который должен её закрыть сразу после загрузки.

Comment: вобщем разобрался как 1 сайт добавить, открывается тот что в коде страницы самый первый открывается.
 но чтоб сразу 5 сатов (5 окон ) открывалось. уму не прложу что не так у  меня в коде

Comment: вот код где 5 сайтов (страниц) https://pastebin.com/YtwcvbhJ